# Function scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

I thought one of the point of functions in javascript was to provide scope.  Things defined in a function were only available inside the function.

```
function cat(name) {
    talk = function() {
        alert(" say meeow!" )
    }
} 

talk()
```

I would expect the above code to fall over because talk should not be visible.  But it is, why?

Comment: Variables default to the global scope when you don't declare them, as I explained in the previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745069/not-a-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you didn't declare it with a `var` keyword.

If you don't use the `var` keyword, it will be in the global scope. If you do use `var`, it will be in the function scope:

```
function cat(name) {
  //anonymous function assigned to the local variable talk
  var talk = function() {
    alert(" say meeow!" )
  };
}
```

You can declare named functions without the `var` keyword, and they will still be in the local scope:

```
function cat(name) {
  //local talk function
  function talk() {
    alert(" say meeow!" )
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually defined the variable in any scope. So it default to global scope.

```
function cat(name) {
    var talk = function() { // <-- added var
        alert(" say meeow!" )
    }
} 

talk() // fail
```

JavaScript allows you to use variables without defining them, this makes the programming language easier to learn and more flexible. I wouldn't recommend you make use of this *feature* though. Always define your variables.

Answer (score 2):

inside of a function, you have to declare variables with "var" or they are declared globally. so you would do:

```
function cat(name) {
    var talk = function() {
        alert(" say meeow!" )
    }
} 

talk() // error: undefined
```